# How to modify default style of tradingview widget indicators?

Tags: javascript, widget, tradingview-api

Right now, I know how to define default inputs for indicators of the widget (see code below). But I want to define default styles. I have not found the right way to do it. Anyone knows?

```
 var chart = new TradingView.widget(
    {
      autosize: true,
      symbol: "OANDA:EURUSD",
      interval: "3",
      timezone: "America/Bogota",
      theme: "dark",
      style: "1",
      locale: "en",

      hide_side_toolbar: true,
      hide_top_toolbar: false,
      toolbar_bg: "#f1f3f6",
      enable_publishing: false,
      allow_symbol_change: true,
      details: false,

      hidevolume: true,

      studies: [

        {
          id: "IchimokuCloud@tv-basicstudies",
          version: 2.0

        },
        {
          id: "Stochastic@tv-basicstudies",
          inputs: {
            K: 3,
          }
        }
      ],
      container_id: "tradingview_7f23e"
    }
  );
```

Comment: What do you mean by default styles ? you want to apply your own custom styles ?

Comment: I want to configure some styles of the indicators, by default. For examble, stochastic lines have a color, I want them to be blue and white by default, as soon as I load the widget.

Thanks in advance if you can help me.

Comment: @NicolasTorres: Same problem here. Very hard to find any documentation...

Answer (score 1):

You should pay for tradingview and check the documentation. but

```
studies_overrides: {
    "volume.volume.color.0": "#00FFFF",
},
```

i think is your answer.
search for `studies_overrides`